# debugging options with rmarkdown

Tags: r-markdown, shiny, rstudio-server

I am using the `rmarkdown` with the `rshiny` for generating `word file` reports. I am using the `R studio-server` for development. On executing the `rshiny` application, it halts due to some error in the one of the `rmarkdown`. 
The error says...

```
Quitting from lines 11-486 (/home/KS127/dev/shiny_apps/pashiny/inst/shiny/dataframe_source.Rmd) 
Quitting from lines NA-486 (/home/KS127/dev/shiny_apps/pashiny/inst/shiny/dataframe_source.Rmd)
```

It's providing the line numbers which are not useful to identify the root cause. Adding print statements are also not useful as I am generating the `word file` report, until and unless the complete `.Rmd` doesn't get successfully executed, I won't be able to see print statements output.

I tried changing the `rmarkdown` output setting from **chunk output inline** to **chunk output to console** as mentioned [here](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/r_notebooks.html) as well but it is of no use.

Is there any way to print the `.Rmd` file print statements or the output to the console or is there any way to debug the .Rmd file?

Comment: Just keep commenting lines out until you find it. Binary search. That is what I do...

Comment: yeah. Doing the same but it's too time consuming.

Comment: You could follow this tweet and move the chunk in question around in your code: https://twitter.com/jennybryan/status/665273964130795520

Comment: @p0bs Surely I will give a try to this one and update my observations here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to my comment above, Abhinandan, I've recently stumbled across a new package, called `testrmd`.

Although it is new, it seems to work with a number of different test packages and provides a useful front-end for Rmarkdown documents. (I'm certainly going to use it.)

You might want to check it out. Here's the link: https://github.com/ropenscilabs/testrmd.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: It is helpful. I am exploring it's features.

Comment: Pleased to hear it

Answer (score 0):

See [My .Rmd file becomes very lengthy. Is that possible split it and source() it's smaller portions from main .Rmd?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56049459/my-rmd-file-becomes-very-lengthy-is-that-possible-split-it-and-source-its-s)

That's what I do. -
Split your code chunks in separate files and add them one by one