# My .Rmd file becomes very lengthy. Is that possible split it and source() it's smaller portions from main .Rmd?

Tags: r, r-markdown

My .Rmd file becomes very lengthy.
Is that possible to split it into several small .Rmd files and then source them somehow from main Rmd file (as we `source()` R files)?

Comment: Maybe something like [child documents](https://yihui.name/knitr/demo/child/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comment above provided elegant solution, as simple as including these lines - they will incluide your child Rmd files into your main Rmd file.

````
```{r includeEndingPart, child = 'part-7-End.Rmd'}
```

```{r includeFAQ, child = 'part-8-FAQ.Rmd'}
```
````

NB: I noted also that you cannot do it from inside child Rmd files.

Answer (score 0):

I think [this SO discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10966109/how-to-source-r-markdown-file-like-sourcemyfile-r) has a nice answer to your question, using `purl()` and `source()`.